# rotating an imageView from a fixed point

Tags: java, android, kotlin, imageview, gauge

i want to create a gauge chart and rotate the indicator from its starting point
im trying to achiving this

[image: gauge chart]

but the indicator not rotating the correct way
and i also tried this for rotating

```kotlin
RotateAnimation(
                    0f, 180f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f
                ).apply {
                    interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
                    duration = 5000
                    repeatCount = 0
                    imgGauge.startAnimation(this)
                }
```

and it's not rotating the correct way also it is in the recyclerView and when the animation end's it reset to it's default

Comment: "not rotating the correct way", can you show or describe how it is rotating instead?

Comment: its in the recycler view i dont know why its return to the default position after the animation end's @ShivamPuri

Answer (score 1):

change `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT` to `Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF`
and add `fillAfter = true` for preventing the imageView from reseting to default

```kotlin
                    RotateAnimation(
                        0f, riskAngle, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f
                    ).apply {
                        interpolator = BounceInterpolator()
                        duration = 750
                        fillAfter = true
                    }.also { image.startAnimation(this) }
```